# QuickSort, crash with some arrays

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort

today I am getting crazy with an easy algorithm for quicksort and a partition with Hoare method.

The code is:

```
static void swap(float **A, int i, int j){
    float *tmp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = tmp;
}

static int partition(float **A, int l, int r){
    int i, j, k;

    i = l - 1;
    j = k = r;

    while(1){
        while ((int)A[++i][0] < (int)A[k][0]);
        while ((int)A[--j][0] > (int)A[k][0]);

        if (j == l || j <= i)
            break;

        swap(A, i, j);
    }

    swap(A, i, k);
    return i;
}

static void quicksortR(float **A, int l, int r){
    int q, i;

    if (r <= l)
        return;

    q = partition(A, l, r);
    quicksortR(A, l, q - 1);
    quicksortR(A, q + 1, r);
}

void sort(float **A, int l, int r){
    quicksortR(A, l, r);
}
```

There is a cast to int because A is a float-pointer array (or a matrix allocated dynamically, btw) where the first column (index = 0) contains an int.

This column is generated with values returned by (rand() % 60) and with a new seed initialized every time the code runs in order to not generate equal number every time.

the matrix is allocated with this function

```
float **floatMatAlloc(int nr, int nc){
    int i;
    float **mat;

    mat = malloc(nr * sizeof(float *));
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++)
        mat[i] = calloc(nc, sizeof(float));

    return mat;
}
```

and the function sort() is called with parameters sort(mat, 0, 9), the floatMatAlloc is called with mat = floatMatAlloc(10, 4).

Using gdb I saw that with some matrix, j index usually became -1, and obviously it crashes, in fact if I put this while in partition()

```
while (--j >= 0 && (int)A[j][0] > (int)A[k][0]);
```

it works! and I don't know why with some matrix, the algorithm implemented by me works and with other matrix it doesn't!

I tried with a classic int array (and not with a pseudo-matrix) and it works with classic while, that is the same while I found in other codes online

Comment: So are you saying that the program works, now that you've added the code to prevent `j` from going below 0?

Comment: @JimMischel Sure, i forgot to say it works with a single int array (and not pseudo-matrix). I will edit the post. 

PS. the while without conditions is the same while I found in other codes online. The point is that j < 0 should not happens!

Comment: k needs to be greater than l and less than r so that the two inner while loops will stop when they reach the pivot value at A[k][0]. At the beginning of partition, set j = r+1, and you might want to set k = (l+r)/2. Also for Hoare method, first recursive call should be | `quicksortR(A, l, q);` (not q-1).